# How to get all related objects of all objects in a Queryset?

Tags: django

Unfortunately I cant find a straight-forward answer to this even though there are several related quesitions.

Say we have:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='subcategories')
```

I know I can get all the subcategories of a specific category by
`some_category.subcategories.all()`

But how do I get a queryset of all subcategories of *all categories in a queryset*?

Comment: `Subcategory.objects.all()`? Since the `ForeignKey` is not NULLable, it means *each* `Subcategory` belongs to exactly *one* `Category`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, it is nullable, I'll edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain all `Subcategory`s that are linked to a collection of `Category`s with:

```
Subcategory.objects.filter(category__in=mycategories)
```

We here use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to retrieve only the `Subcategory`s for which the category is in `mycategories`.

Comment: I dont think this solves my issue, because I dont want all subs of every category existing. I only want those that their category is in my filtered queryset.

Comment: @eva: ah, then you do this with an `__in` lookup, see edit.